# How to insert Prefix values to specific Number in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following use case in Oracle SQL:

I want to fill up a number with the value 0, if the number was only the length 1. Here is an example:

```
'9'  (must be convert to '09')
'2'  (must be convert to '02')
'16' (must be convert to '16')
```

How can I do this in Oracle SQL?

Thanks for helping me

Comment: you could done it using scripting language before inserting in table...Is it compulsory using sql ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LPAD` function.

The syntax is like this:

```
LPAD ( string1, padded_length, [ pad_string ] )
```

So in your case it can be something like:

```
SELECT LPAD(MY_COLUMN, 2, '0') AS PADDED_VALUE
  FROM MY_TABLE
```

You can read more documentation in [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions082.htm) or [Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php). The second one has slightly better examples.